# RowUniqueID in filtered row

Tags: c#, asp.net

could somebody help me in C# programing in an web application. Namely, how can we find out RecordUniqueId of the filtered row....in order to further edit (i.e., set values in some other columns in the same row), based on RecordUniqueId value? Or, is it possible to, upon clicking on enter button in order to search for certain row, to immediately have some actions performed on the values in some other columns of filtered row? Let me say in other words, to have some kind of automation of editing  values in some other columns of the filtered row?

Thanks in advance

```
public class PartyVuk2010GENTableControlRow : BasePartyVuk2010GENTableControlRow
{
      
                
}

public class PartyVuk2010GENTableControl : BasePartyVuk2010GENTableControl
{
    
        public override void MarkDiscontinued_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs args)
{
     try {
          DbUtils.StartTransaction();
 
          foreach (PartyVuk2010GENTableControlRow rc in this.GetSelectedRecordControls()) {
              PartyVuk2010GENRecord rec;
 
              
              rec = PartyVuk2010GENTable.GetRecord(rc.RecordUniqueId, true);
              if (rec != null) {
              rec.Discontinued = true;
           rec.Test = "10";
                
                
rec.BallotOrder = PartyVuk2010GENTable.Instance.GetLargest()+1;



                   rec.Save();
              }
          }
 
          DbUtils.CommitTransaction();
     }
     catch (Exception ex) {
 
         BaseClasses.Utils.MiscUtils.RegisterJScriptAlert(this, "BUTTON_CLICK_MESSAGE", ex.Message);
     }
     finally {
          DbUtils.EndTransaction();
     }
 
          this.DataChanged = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your code?

Comment: Why no one don't share their code? Im seeing the same answer below many posts, share your code etc. Trust us we are trying to help ;)